# Azure Mobile app service & EF Table Column Restriction?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, odata, azure-mobile-services

I am using an Azure Mobile app service with Odata and Entity Framework. I have table that has around 90 columns and it doesn't work unless i comment out some of the columns in the data model. It doesn't matter what columns I comment out a query won't work if with all the columns.

The azure mobile service debugger tells me:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll" The odata query works fine and returns 200 ok but then the EF talking to the SQL (it's an azure sql server) has a freakout and never returns anything... until i remove some columns from the datamodel.

This is just with the datamodels and tablecontrollers defined out of the box and i'm sending queries with Postman. I have 20 other tables in this service that work perfectly. I can't find a size limit or anything base on number of columns you can use with this. Any help is awesome.

Postman gives me:
"502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server" but that is too generic to trace. looked in all the azure logs that are possible and nothing. just said there was an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 8 months of randomly trying I actually got it working!

Instead of returning the `IQueryable` directly from the helper that's built into the `AzureMobileServiceServer` namespace convert it to an `IEnumerable`, then re-select everything then change it back to an `IQueryable`.

No idea why this works but it negates the stackoverflow problem that is happening otherwise. I think this adds a bit more time when syncing offline but if it works I'll take it.

```
public IQueryable<ItemLibrary> GetAllItemLibrarys()
{
    // return Query();     // !! this is the original from the table controller
    return Query().AsEnumerable()
                  .Select(s => s).AsQueryable(); //  !! replace with this
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) for your mobile app to collection the detailed error message. Also, you could modify your TableController and log the detailed SQL statement as follows:

```
protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
    base.Initialize(controllerContext);
    var context = new MobileServiceContext();

    //add this line
    context.Database.Log += (msg) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"{msg}{Environment.NewLine}");
    };
    DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<Message>(context, Request);
}
```

Also, you could execute your relevant SQL statement via SSMS and check the query execution plan to narrow this issue. Moreover, for your mobile client, you could only retrieve the specific columns from your remote table. Here the code snippet for C#:

```
var query =
    from r in table.CreateQuery()
    select new { r.Text, r.Complete, r.UpdatedAt, r.Version };
```

Comment: the diagnostics aren't telling me anything other than what i posted. the query isn't even making it to the SQL server for it to log it. I'm doing about 1,000 queries in the same service everyday now. it's just that one table that has more than 90 columns

Comment: I found an article that entity and odata won't query more than 94? columns. but they couldn't figure out how to get past it either...

Comment: I just found the similar issue mentioned about request likes this `http://localhost/odata/entity?$select=col1,col2,...col99,col100`. Could you provide the blog and provide the request you sent?

Comment: Sorry I can't can't it now, but they said you can't do more than 96 columns. and I've triple verified it won't let me do that. I have dozens of tables going just fine for over a year through the web service. but if i do 96+ columns it doesn't work. I split my large tables up into different views. I don't show all of those 96+ columns on one page in my client apps anyway so it wan't a big deal after all.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/5131 this is the link, but still can't figure out how to do it. Found out I need to do it after all...

Comment: But it is definitely narrowed down to a limitation with the IQueryable Expression Tree